# Objective-C: Are all string literals always loaded into memory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, nsstring

In `UIViewController` subclasses, I often see:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", nil);
    }
    return self;
}
```

1. Why not set `self.title` in `-viewDidLoad`?
2. Are all string literals always loaded into memory?

Comment: In order to be used by current processor activity, any piece of data *must* be loaded into memory, either a register or as an address - Perhaps this isn't the question you're trying to ask, can you clarify ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are compiled into your executable file - they are not resources. They are kept in the initialized static data section in the executable. So yes, on the most basic level they are in memory whenever the executable is loaded - that is, whenever the program is running.

There is paging though.  Somtetimes, when the memory runs low, it's possible that the system throws parts of your running executable out of memory to free up some, and reloads them once they're needed. This process is automatic, transparent, and unpredictable. So there's a minor chance that the string is not physically in memory at some point in time, but once you try to access it, it will magically be there. Any paging is never done on per-string basis - it's done in units of 4-8 KB ("pages").

Comment: so then if all string literals are always loaded into memory, then it makes sense to set `self.title` once in `-initWithNibName:bundle:` instead of in `-viewDidLoad` because setting `self.title` to `nil` in `-viewDidUnload` will not free up any memory. Correct?

Comment: It will not free any memory indeed. However, initializing view controllers is typically done in `viewDidLoad`. `init` methods of library classes are somewhat brittle - there might be several `initWithXXX` methods, and in some circumstances the system might call some exotic one that you never cared to override, and your init code won't be called.

Comment: Right, but for [`UIViewController`, `-initWithNibName:bundle:`](http://j.mp/q61Yv6) is the [designated initializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126726/ios-uiview-subclass-init-or-initwithframe/7126874#7126874).

Answer (score 7):

In general, string literals are part of the data section in the compiled Mach-O file.  Since all of the code is loaded "into memory" when being executed, that means that the string literals are always loaded into memory as well.  This being said, it is still a good idea to retain/release strings just as you would other objects, even if you know that they are going to be literals.

In the example you provided, the `NSLocalizedString` call is being used for [Internationalization](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/).  This has nothing to do (memory wise) with the string that you are supplying.