# Which UIViewController properties should I set in -initWithNibName:bundle: vs. -viewDidLoad?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, init, viewdidload, viewdidunload

I understand that I should [set `self.title` in `-initWithNibName:bundle:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296739/objective-c-are-all-string-literals-always-loaded-into-memory/7297130#7297130).

1. What about `self.navigationItem.titleView`?

   Since `self.navigationItem.titleView` seems only to be used when `self.view` is loaded, I'm thinking I should, to save memory, set `self.navigationItem.titleView` in `-viewDidLoad` and nil it in `-viewDidUnload`, e.g.:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
   }

   - (void)viewDidUnload {
       self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
       [super viewDidUnload];
   }
   ```
2. What about `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems to work OK to set `self.navigationItem.titleView` in `-viewDidLoad` and nil it in `-viewDidUnload`.
2. You should set `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` in `-initWithNibName:bundle` because if you push two view controllers without animation `-viewDidLoad` will not get called for the first view controller that's pushed. So, if that view controller sets `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` in `-viewDidLoad`, it will actually not get set, and the back button on the second view controller will just default to the title of the first view controller as usual.